# Raspberry Pi 4: Unable to reboot (unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179 2)

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os

When leaving home last week, my Raspberry Pi 4 was working properly. After coming back today, I was wondering why all of my smart home stuff isn't working anymore, SSH doesn't work either. So I connected the Raspi via HDMI to a monitor, attached a USB keyboard and now I'm seeing the following error:

```
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2) ]---
```

Here's an image of the full error stack I'm seeing on the monitor:
[image]

Of course, I started searching around and found plenty of links, but many of them either refer to pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>/using NOOBS (does not seem to work anymore with the latest versions of Raspberry Pi OS) or using another Linux installation (why I don't have, only a Win11 laptop with WSL2 enabled (for Docker)).

Is there any way how I can rescue my Pi using my Windows device?

Thx a lot!

Comment: Restore from your backup (preferably to a new SD Card).

Comment: Most likely a failed SD card

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you think the SD card is broken in my case whereas in other cases with the same error, users could resolve it without switching to a new SD card?

Comment: The error "I/O error" indicate a faulty SD card

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "rescue my Pi" (whatever that means) and don't have Linux you can do a fresh install on a new SD Card then use that to mount your old SD Card (in a SD Card reader) and read the contents.